# write items from a list to a text file in different line

Tags: python

I'm trying to get user inputs a few times and then save those inputs to a list and after that write list items to a text file.
the list would look like this with the inputs.

```
prog_input = [120,0,0,100,20,0,100,0,20]
```

I wrote this to a text file using:

```
txtfile1 = open("Input progression data.txt", "w+")
txtfile1.write(', '.join([str(item) for item in prog_input])+ '\n')
```

This just print them in a line.()

The output I'm trying to get is(in the text file):

```
120,0,0
100,20,0
100,0,20
```

Comment: Are you always going to take 9 inputs? Or you just want to split whatever input you get into lines with 3 elements in each line?

Comment: How are you viewing the resulting file? What operating system and program do you open it with?

Answer (score 0):

`prog_input` is just a flattened list, so you need to group your items into chunks and then output to your file

```
prog_input = [120, 0, 0, 100, 20, 0, 100, 0, 20]
step = 3
with open("Input progression data.txt", "w+") as myfile:
    for chunk in [prog_input[n:n+step] for n in range(0, len(prog_input), step)]:
        myfile.write(','.join(map(str, chunk)) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want 3 values per line. So...

```
F = "Input progression data.txt"
prog_input = [120,0,0,100,20,0,100,0,20]
with open(F, 'w') as outfile:
    for o in range(0, len(prog_input), 3):
        print(','.join(map(str, prog_input[o:o+3])), file=outfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.array_split` to split your list into sub-lists of size 3 each:

```
import numpy as np

prog_input = [120,0,0,100,20,0,100,0,20]
with open("Input progression data.txt", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write("\n".join([", ".join(map(str, chunk)) for chunk in np.array_split(prog_input, 3)]))
```

Answer (score -1):

Move the `\n` to the right location
This:

```py
', '.join([str(item) for item in prog_input])+ '\n'
```

Should be :

```py
',\n'.join([str(item) for item in prog_input])
```

### Edit:

If you want only 3 elements on each line you can use:

```py
',\n'.join([', '.join([str(j) for j in prog_input[i:i+3]]) for i in range(0, len(prog_input), 3)])
```

Comment: Did you test this and compare against the OP's desired output? Neither version you have given works they way they want.

Comment: Someone edited the OP while i was answering...

Comment: I see...the OP's formatting got mangled because they just used line breaks. However, your attempts still wouldn't give the desired output as it was rendered from the original version of the OP's question.

Answer (score -1):

```
', '.join([str(item) for item in prog_input]
```

This loops over the entire list and joins all of the elements with comma delimiters. If you want the output to be something else, then you need to do this differently.

I suggest describing in words what you want to do. From your example, it appears that you first need to take the list and subdivide it into lists with three elements each. I leave writing code to do that as an exercise to the reader.